# Drag & Drop Function Not Working - Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, drag-and-drop, flash-cs4

I am trying to create a function in ActionScript that shall trigger an event when a drag-gable object is dropped over another object.

```
var hits = 0;

// Register mouse event functions
answer_j.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
answer_j.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_e.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_e.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_a1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_a1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_t.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_a2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_a2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

answer_n.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
answer_n.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

// Define a mouse down handler (user is dragging) 
function mouseDownHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{   
    var object = evt.target;    
    // limit dragging to the area inside the canvas     
    object.startDrag(); 
}

function mouseUpHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {  
    var obj = evt.target;   
    // obj.dropTarget will give us the reference to the shape of    
    // the object over which we dropped the circle.     
    var target = obj.dropTarget;    
    // If the target object exists the we ask the test_match function   
    // to compare moved obj and target where it was dropped.    
    if (target != null)     
    {       
        test_match(target, obj);    
    }   
    obj.stopDrag(); 
}

function test_match(target,obj) {   
    // test if either one of the four pairs match   
    if ( (target == box_j && obj == answer_j) ||    
        (target == box_e && obj == answer_e) ||     
        (target == box_m && obj == answer_m) ||     
        (target == box_b && obj == answer_b) ||     
        (target == box_a1 && obj == answer_a1) ||   
        (target == box_t && obj == answer_t) ||     
        (target == box_a2 && obj == answer_a2) ||   
        (target == box_n && obj == answer_n) )  
    { // we got a hit       
        hits = hits+1;      
        textField.text = "Yes ! You got one !";         
        // make the object transparent      
        obj.alpha = 0.5;        
        // kill its event listeners - object can't be moved anymore         
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);                  
        obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);       
        // Test if we are done      
        if (hits == 8) {            
            textField.text = "Made it !!"; 
        } 
    } else {        
            textField.text = "Missed :(";
    } 
}
```

box_j - box_n are the objects that shall be the target for the drag-gable objects.

However, for certain unknown reasons the above code won't work. Kindly please advise if you know how to resolve it.

All object are in "movie clip" type.

Comment: What won't work exactly? Errors occur? You can't drag the movieclip or it don't stop drag or the test_match? But I think I have an idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order inside your mouseUpHandler function.

Stop the drag before you reference the dropTarget when this don't work you should add .parent to the dropTarget:

```
function mouseUpHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {  
    var obj = evt.target;   

    obj.stopDrag(); 
    // obj.dropTarget will give us the reference to the shape of    
    // the object over which we dropped the circle.   
    var target = obj.dropTarget;  
    //var target = obj.dropTarget.parent; 

    // If the target object exists the we ask the test_match function   
    // to compare moved obj and target where it was dropped.    
    if (target != null) { 
        test_match(target, obj); 
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

This is why you have to use `.parent` sometimes:

> When you put the target on the stage in the authoring mode and not
>   through AS then the dropTarget property will reference the Shape. To
>   get the instance of the MovieClip or Sprite that contains the
>   Shape you need to use the parent parameter.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I have tried it, yet still not working, this is one of the error message btw`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at test_fla::MainTimeline/test_match()
 at test_fla::MainTimeline/mouseUpHandler()`

Comment: Don't use `target == box_e` inside your test_match() function, use target.name instead: `target.name == "box_e"`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: That null reference error would only occur if the `textField` variable does not exist by the time the handler is called.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de The null reference error occurs when a field is called on an object that does not exist, i.e. `target == box_e ` can't be the culprit - if either were null, the expression would still be valid: `null== box_e` or `target == null` are perfectly legal.  It has to be the calls to `textField.text`. The only other explanation would be if all of `target`, `obj`, and the named instances were all `null`- in that case the calls to `obj.alpha`, etc. would cause such an error.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't gave my comment that much thought, I only thought when the error occurs on the MainTimeline, the textfield must be on stage and isn't generated with script. So I shutted out the textfield as error source.